# How to zoom an image that in scroll?

Tags: iphone

I want to do an animation in which i have different images in scroll view.I want that when an image comes in center it should zoom like an animation done in Net-a-porter magazine app...

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scroll view delegate to find out which imageview to be zoomed.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
CGPoint pt= scrollView.contentOffset;
CGSize content_size=,scrollView.contentSize;
//find out image to be zoomed and call animateCurrentImage
}
```

Animate the image in the center note that imageview.

```
- (void)animateCurrentImage:(UIImageView *)currentImage {



    if(prevImage)
    {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        prevImage.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    currentImage.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [self notePreviousImage:currentImage];


}
- (void)notePreviousImage:(UIImageView *)currentImage 
{
    prevImage=currentImage;
    [prevImage retain]; //only if required

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `zoomScale` property, or the `-zoomToRect:animated:` method.

If you want to use `zoomScale` pls note to change the scale within an `animation` block using `UIViewAnimation`.